# Show UIButton over an Admob Banner?

Tags: ios, uibutton, admob

I'm trying to display a UIButton over an AdmobBanner like the example below (the black X obviously). I looked for this option in the Admob SDK but couldn't find anything.

I've tried selecting the button->Editor->Arrange->Send to Front with no results.

[image: X in Corner]

Help is much appreciated.

This is the code I use to show my banner:

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                origin:origin];

// Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
// before compiling.
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a150xxxxxxxxxxx";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
self.adBanner.center =
CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming you're using interface builder here, and that both the AdMob view and your button are subviews of the same parent view. If that is the case, just make sure the button comes before the AdMob view in the list of subviews in the Objects pane on the left.

Another option is to make the following call in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button]
```

Make sure you do this after inserting the AdMob view, if you're doing it programmatically

Comment: That didn't work, banner still loaded over the button. Also, Admob doesn't show up in the Objects pane on the left, admob is setup in the viewdidload.

Comment: are you calling `bringSubviewToFront` after all of the code you posted? and it still appears behind the Ad view?

Comment: Nope I wasn't. I put it just before that. Thanks alot! Answer accepted!

Comment: great! glad to know i could help :)